# How can I reversibly randomize/encrypt unsigned integers from 0 to approx. 2^24?

Tags: php, security, ssl, encryption

**Background/context**
*This information may provide additional contextualizing insight but is not required reading to understand the fundamental basics of my question, listed below.*

As part of a high-reliability secure protocol stack I'm designing, I'm chunking the SSL datastream into "frames" or "blocks" to increase network reliability and mitigate underlying network corruption: dropped/corrupted/mis-transmitted frames will be able to be retransmitted, and my network layer will also be highly tolerant of physical disconnects. To accomplish these feats, the frames will include a frame ID, the frame blocksize, and a frame checksum.

My problem is that, this "framing layer" must necessarily be unencrypted because it needs to verify the data blocks arrived successfully, *before* decryption is attempted... and since this whole stack will be open source, it'd be exceptionally easy for an attacker to decipher the frame header data and immediately know whether they were looking at valid or corrupt data. The encryption layer will be using SSL secured using public and private keys on both ends so decryption would be notably nontrivial, but I still want to eliminate even this small attack vector.

Earlier today I was idly pondering all of this and came up with an interesting idea: both ends of the link agree on some obfuscation protocol/scheme parameters that "scramble" the ID/size/checksum data in a reversible way. This agreement would occur *inside the SSL layer*... meaning the whole SSL datastream would need to be decoded for the header info to make sense... but this action would suddenly be significantly harder to do because the ID/size/checksum headers would essentially be meaningless "line noise" at this point, and if I randomize the block sizes slightly, the header positions would become unpredictable, and decryption would essentially become a giant experiment in removing random bytes from the datastream... sending attack difficulty through the roof.

At least, I think it would work out like this. I'm not a cryptanalyst/cryptographer, and this is my first ever secure protocol design. Maybe someone can call me out and tell me if I'm talking through my hat here.

<sup>Also, rubber-duck programming really works: I thought I'd mention I came up with the blocksize-randomization thing while typing this post. ^^</sup>

**My question**

I need a small collection of algorithms that I can randomly stack one or more of on top of each other, each of which will take one or more modifiable parameters, and use said parameter(s) to transform a variable-bitwidth number such that it has no bearing on its original value.

Most importantly, I need a way to reverse the "encrypted" value back to its original value when I supply the list of algorithms that were run and the parameter(s) used.

While I would prefer if the output of these algorithms were kept to the same number of physical bytes to transmit as I have in my current design, I don't mind slightly larger network payloads if it increases security.
(Currently the header is currently 2-3 bytes: a 15-bit ID, a 1 bit "size scale" flag, and either an 8-bit (1-256 byte) or 16-bit (257-65791 byte) blocksize value.)

Also, FWIW, this system will likely span multiple languages, but I'm currently implementing/prototyping it in PHP (as a console script), since I currently have the most experience with this language.

Comment: PHP has a lot of encryption functionality available to it, both symmetric and public key, have you looked at the relevant sections of the manual?

Comment: @GordonM: I've decided to use phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sf.net/) for the SSL layer, since it's faster than PHP's OpenSSL libraries. You make a good point, no way am I reimplementing all *THAT* :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Encrypting an Integer

Convert to a string, then encrypt it like normal.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Encrypt an integer using libsodium.
 * Requires PHP 7.2+ or paragonie/sodium_compat.
 *
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013001/2224584
 * @param int $integer
 * @param string $key
 * @return string
 */
function encryptInteger(int $int, string $key): string
{
    $littleEndian = pack('V', $int);
    $nonce = random_bytes(24);
    return sodium_bin2hex(
        $nonce .
        sodium_crypto_secretbox($littleEndian, $nonce, $key)
    );
}

/**
 * Decrypt an integer using libsodium.
 * Requires PHP 7.2+ or paragonie/sodium_compat.
 *
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013001/2224584
 * @param string $ciphertext
 * @param string $key
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function decryptInteger(string $ciphertext, string $key): int
{
    $decoded = sodium_hex2bin($ciphertext);
    if (!is_string($decoded)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid encoding');
    }
    if (mb_strlen($decoded, '8bit') < 40) {
        throw new Exception('Message too short!');
    }
    $nonce = mb_substr($decoded, 0, 24, '8bit');
    $encrypted = mb_substr($decoded, 24, null, '8bit');
    $decrypted = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open(
        $encrypted,
        $nonce,
        $key
    );
    if (!is_string($decrypted)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid ciphertext');
    }
    $unpacked = unpack('V', $decrypted);
    if (!is_array($unpacked)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid value');
    }
    return (int) array_shift($unpacked);
}
```

You can see this code in action [here](https://3v4l.org/cAWav) (requires PHP 7.2). This uses **authenticated encryption** and handles the nonce for you.

#### Predictable Random Integers

See [SeedSpring](https://github.com/paragonie/seedspring), which generates deterministic pseudorandom output from a secret seed, using AES-CTR.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a block cipher with a large enough block size to hold the maximum number of bits you require: 15 + 1 + 16 = 32 bits.  Either DES (64 bit) or AES (128 bit) has a large enough block size to handle this, albeit with some space overhead.  If the overhead is too much, then the [Speck cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_%28cipher%29) has a 32 bit block size option, and could be a better fit, but that is nowhere near as well supported in libraries as DES or AES.

Comment: Or AES in any streaming mode like CTR with a fixed size to 24 bits.

Comment: Hrm, this sounds quite interesting to consider. The Speck cipher looks especially practical since it looks quite it has very low overhead, like you said. I don't need library support; a sample C encoder implementation is right on Wikipedia, I just need to find a decoder and it'd be a straight port. Thinking further about it, AES or DES might prove invaluable if I need more bits; how might I get into using one of those? That is, where might I find sample encoder/decoder implementations, or what library functions should I look for?

Comment: Another consideration I just realized I'll likely need to take into account is that PHP tends to choke if asked to natively process numbers that are very large; in particular it can produce tragically inconsistent results across 32-bit and 64-bit platforms under certain circumstances. It's vital my routines work across architectural bitwidths, and I'm already accounting for this elsewhere using GMP. Simpler algorithms would be preferable because I'm likely going to need to roll GMP-based implementations for this portion of the system too. Heh